# More efficient way to purrr::map2 for a large dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

Is there a faster way to do the following, where in the real application, `df` has many rows (and therefore `list_of_colnames` has the same number of elements):

```
list_of_colnames <- list(c("A", "B"), c("A"))
some_vector <- c("fish", "cat")

map2(split(df, seq(nrow(df))), list_of_colnames, function(row, colnames) {
    row$indicator <- ifelse(any(row[, colnames] %in% some_vector), 1, 0)
    return(row)
  })
```

While this current implementation works, it takes centuries for the big `df`. In fact I think `split()` is a major bottleneck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be to make use of `row/column` indexing

```
rowind <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(list_of_colnames) * nrow(df))
df$indicator <- +(tapply(c(t(df[unlist(list_of_colnames)])) %in% some_vector,
       rowind, FUN = any))
```

-output

```
> df
      A   B indicator
1  fish   A         1
2 hello cat         1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A =  c('fish', 'hello'), B = c('A', 'cat'))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun ! Though When I tried to set 
`df <- data.frame(A =  c('foo', 'hello'), B = c('A', 'cat'))`
Then I get 
`> df`

`      A   B indicator`

`1   foo   A         1`

`2 hello cat         0`

Comment: @Alex I updated my example and code.  Can you check that

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to still be doing the same?

Comment: @Alex I get `> df$indicator
[1] 1 1`

Comment: I meant I get 1 1.  There was a mixup earlier in my console, but the code seems to be getting both 1s

Comment: The problem shows up when I changed  "fish" to "foo" and yet for row 1, the indicator still flags 1, while the 2nd row with "cat" now flags 0??

Comment: @Alex sorry, there was a bug.  Change it to `c(t(` instead of `unlist` as unlst does by column unlist.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid splitting your data frame into a list all together and instead apply your condition across the rows using `rowwise` and `c_across` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_of_colnames <- list(c("A", "B"), c("A"))
some_vector <- c("fish", "cat")

map(list_of_colnames, ~ 
      df %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(indicator = as.numeric(any(c_across(all_of(.x)) %in% some_vector))) %>% 
      ungroup()
    )
```

**Output**

Still mapping over `list_of_columns` returns a list output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  A     B     C     indicator
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
1 fish  dog   bird  TRUE     
2 dog   cat   bird  TRUE     
3 bird  lion  cat   FALSE    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  A     B     C     indicator
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
1 fish  dog   bird  TRUE     
2 dog   cat   bird  FALSE    
3 bird  lion  cat   FALSE
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(A = c("fish", "dog", "bird"), B = c("dog", "cat", 
"lion"), C = c("bird", "bird", "cat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```